# Windows port forwarding, local machine to server

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, windows-firewall, openstack, windows-8

I'm working on Windows 8. I'm trying to connect to an OpenStack cloud which is hosted on a remote server but has a public IP to the API. However, making API calls require calls to additional services inside the cloud which still have the internal addresses of the cloud, and I cannot do this.

All of the internal addresses have been set up so that they have a public equivalent now. So for every private `10.x.x.2:yyyyy` now I have a `194.x.x.x:zzzzz`.

What I need to do is set up port forwarding on my local machine, so that each call to `10.x.x.2:yyyyy` of the application calling the API will get translated to the corresponding `194.x.x.x:zzzzz` which is public.

I've tried netsh with

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=yyyy listenaddress=10.x.x.2 connectport=zzzzz connectaddress=194.x.x.x
```

but this has yielded no results.

I also tried using a PassPort tool that I found online, running it with admin privileges and doing the same thing, but again to no avail. I first try to test the `10.x.x.x:yyyy` address in a browser, and then test with the application, but it hasn't worked a single time.

Firewall is down.

Comment: For anyone interested, I didn't find a way to solve this. I worked around by getting remote access to the private network through team viewer and rdp. I think it's something to do with the router ports. But I'm not sure yet.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is right, you just need to enable ipv6 while using portproxy **v4tov4**

To install IPv6:

1. Open Network Connections.
2. Right-click any local area connection, and then click
3. Click Install.
4. In the Select Network Component Type dialog box, click Protocol, and
   then click Add.
5. In the Select Network Protocol dialog box, click Microsoft TCP/IP
   version 6, and then click OK.
6. Click Close to save changes to your network connection.

> Alternatively you could use a third party port forwarder application like: [Albertino port mapper](https://www.rekings.com/albertino-port-mapper/)